# How would you make a text cell in a an Outline View show how many children the parent row has?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

How would you make Rows that are the Top Parent in an Outline View (which is connected to a NSTreeController) display how many children it has in a Text Cell?

If this is a bit confusing here is a Picture of what I mean.

[image]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://allusions.sourceforge.net/articles/images/ordered.jpg))</sub>

I am talking about the number to the right of one of the rows in the circle, which is displaying how many children the parent has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom cell, either on that column or on a second column.

Comment: Do you know where I might get it?

Comment: Is there a web page where I might find some advice on how to make my own?

Comment: Sadly, no. There is a page titled “Subclassing NSCell”, but it's incomplete to the point of uselessness. Fortunately, it's not too difficult: Make a subclass of NSCell, implement one or both of the public drawing methods, and make it handle an object value that is an instance of one of your model classes.

Comment: It would be even easier if you went the two-column route: the custom cell in the second column would only need only to be able to handle an NSNumber. The trick, though, would be sizing the second column correctly, which is why I'd do one-column and make my cell completely app-specific.

Comment: I will give it go, and will try the two column route.

Answer (score 3):

You can either make a custom NSCell subclass that will show the child count (you would use your model object itself as the cell's object value, instead of providing a separate string or image), or in your data source method for the outline view you could just include the count along with the title string. Of course, you'll have to use the first option if you want it drawn exactly like the screenshot.

Comment: How would i, in the data source method for the outline view could I include the count along with the title string?

Comment: Joshua: +[NSString stringWithFormat:]. As he says, though, simply formatting the number into the string won't make it look like the screenshot; you need a custom cell for that.